# When using python and selenium how to find the presence of an element based on id and value

Tags: jquery, python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find the presence of an element by finding the length of the jquery.
How can we capture the length of a webelement in a variable, so that I can check the value of the variable to make decision.

Or is there any other way to accomplish the same result. I am using python, selenium webdriver and JQuery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by length of a Web Element? There is many way to check the presence of the web element. But i am bit confused by the word length. Make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to find length of element text using python webdriver. See the below code.

```
name=driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
print name.text
len(name)
```

above code will show the length of element which you can pick from website. May be it is help full for you.

Comment: Hi Senthil, I found that the len(name) only works for name=driver.find_elements_by_xpath and not for find_element. Is this true.

Comment: Hi Smith,yes. its true try it. i have tried like that only and i got length of string also.

Answer (score 0):

We can Use this Funda

If driver.findElements(By.id(id)).size() > 0 Then
  Element Present;
Else
  Element Not Present

Same Applies for Value.

Please Let me know is my Funda OK or NOT.